# Update different column at different row with JPQL

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data, jpql

I have a table, I need to update one value in a row, based on the value of another column in that row find and update a value the new found row as well. How can this be achieved with JPQL?

Example

Table Information

```
Name   AddInfo   Interest   Count
abc              xyz        
xyz                         9
```

Lets say, I get name as abc, AddInfo as def and count as 10.

I should update the AddInfo as def for the row with name as abc and update the count as 10 for the row which has the name same as the Interest of the row with name abc, ie the row with name as xyz.

Final output as below.

```
Name   AddInfo   Interest   Count
abc    def        xyz        
xyz                         10
```

Comment: Just execute two statements.

Comment: could you please give me an example.